# org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException trying to connect a MYSQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, maven, jdbc

Im trying to connect a MySQL database to my java springboot project, but i got a org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException error, i already tried to change spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update, and its still wrong.

Error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table to_do (id integer not null, desc varchar(255), done bit not null, target_date date, username varchar(255), primary key (id)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc varchar(255), done bit not null, target_date date, username varchar(255), p' at line 1]
```

Properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/ spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp logging.level.org.springframework=info logging.level.com.pao.springboot.myFirstWebApp=debug

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/todos spring.datasource.username=todos-user spring.datasource.password=dummytodos spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

```
    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>glassfish-jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap-datepicker</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>`
```

Entity:

```
ackage com.pao.springboot.myFirstWebApp.toDo;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.time.LocalDate;

//Database
// List of todos

@Entity(name = "ToDo")
public class toDo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String desc;
    private LocalDate targetDate;
    private boolean done;
    
    
    public toDo(){}
    
    public toDo(int id, String username, String desc, LocalDate targetDate, boolean done) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
        this.done = done;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    
    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
    public LocalDate getTargetDate() {
        return targetDate;
    }
    
    public void setTargetDate(LocalDate targetDate) {
        this.targetDate = targetDate;
    }
    
    public boolean isDone() {
        return done;
    }
    
    public void setDone(boolean done) {
        this.done = done;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "toDo{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", user='" + username + '\'' +
                ", desc='" + desc + '\'' +
                ", targetDate=" + targetDate +
                ", done=" + done +
                '}';
    }

}
```

I hope someone can help me, thanks to read me.

I already tried to change spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause is simple - `DESC` is a reserved keyword in MySQL (and in SQL in general), used to specify descending order, so you may want to name your column explicitly:

```java
@Column(name = "description")
private String desc;
```

UPD:
please don't forget to import corrent @Column:

```java
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
```

Comment: It's true! I didn't take that in consideration, thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to help! You may mark this question as accepted if that works :]